# Allow application to access specific usb device

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb

On raspberry-pi, I need to work with two devices via usb. The device comes with a proprietary library that allows me to work with only one device. I need to work with two. I'm trying to create an environment that for the program would look like only one usb device is connected. Somehow spread the application spaces.
Running two docker containers with mounting only specific devices `-v/dev/bus/usb/001` or `-v/dev/bus/usb/002` with the creation of the link `ln 002->001` did not help.

```bash
docker run -it --rm \
    -v $PWD:/mnt \
    -v /dev/bus/usb/$1/dev/bus/usb/$1 \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    $TAG
```

(Starting the second instance
of the application generates an
error `../../libusb/os/threads_posix.h:46: usbi_mutex_lock: 'Assertion pthread_mutex_lock(mutex) == 0' failed`.)

Are there any mechanisms of isolation and substitution of usb devices?